# android emulator for google api level XX, how do I set the network

Tags: android, networking, emulation

I launch the avd for google api level 12

I want to set the network so the emulator can connect to internet. Not like the Android X.X emulator which can be set by `adb shell`, `setprop net.dns1`

The Google API emulator has multi dns
After I set every DMS to the DNS server of my PC, it still can not connect to the internet.

I want to learn the useful command to diagnose the network. Any ideas?